# How to measure Tobin's q?

Tags: reference-request, finance, empirical-evidence

How do people calculate Tobin'q empirically?

Does anyone use it to make investment decisions? In particular, the version I learnt has no company debt involved with only capital under consideration, will this affect empirical research?

Comment: Average or marginal Q?

Comment: I don't know there's a Average and Marginal Q. I'm taking a course in Graduate MacroEcon, the Q we covered was equivalent to the Market to Book ratio of the market.

Comment: That's average Q. Q is the ratio of an asset's market value to the replacement cost of that asset. In some macro finance models a firm makes marginal investments until the market value of an additional investment exactly equals its replacement cost. This gives a marginal Q of 1. But along the way initial investments would be higher than one (diminishing marginal value of capital). So even if all firms had a marginal Q of 1 they might have very different average Q.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Is there any good empirical reference I can consult from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in Tobin's (average) q,  you might find useful *A Simple Approximation of Tobin's q* ([Chung and Pruitt (1994)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3665623?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)). That paper has a highly accurate approximation for Tobin's Q using Compustat. While the JSTOR copy I linked to is pay-walled, other versions appear not to be.